# django - forms- Field error - Unknown field(s) (a, l, _) specified for <tablename>

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a form, inside forms.py I have:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from ver11.models import studentdetails
class studentform(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model=studentdetails
          fields='__all__'
```

But I get the following error:

`Unknown field(s) (a, l, _) specified for studentdetails`

please guide me through this

Comment: obviously i have gone through it that's why i am asking here . It might be a silly error , but it is creating difficulty for me

Comment: When i replaced __all__ with the list containing all the fields of the studentdetails table , it works fine . But what is the issue with using '__all__'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using Django 1.5 or previous version. `__all__` only exists in Django 1.6+:

> Before version 1.6, the '**all**' shortcut did not exist, but omitting
>   the fields attribute had the same effect. Omitting both fields and
>   exclude is now deprecated, but will continue to work as before until
>   version 1.8

So change your code to:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from ver11.models import studentdetails

class studentform(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = studentdetails
          # omit the fields totally
```

Also please read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for name convention and style.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it helps ;). And remember to read PEP8, the name convention in your code is quite bad to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.5 or before, fields should be an itterable, like a list or a tuple, you're giving it a string, which is also an iterable, but it is interpreted as `('a', 'l', '_')`

try with

```
fields = ['__all__']
```

however, you can just leave it out, all is default.

Also note that `fields = ('__all__')` will still give you this error since this isn't a real tuple, you'd need `fields = ('__all__',)` to convince python you meant a tuple.

Comment: This is incorrect. While ``fields`` needs to be an iterable, you can also assign `'__all__'` as its value and it has the effect of all the `Model`'s fields to be included. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use).

Comment: I believe this has changed since django 1.7 (possibly 1.6/1.5?) Probably because a lot of people were making this mistake. But it certainly wasn't the case in django 1.4 https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.X/topics/forms/modelforms.html I clearly remember running into this problem myself. The advice of leaving it out since it's the default is valid in all versions of django I used.

Comment: Well yes, I forgot to mention that this is what is *currently* the case. I don't remember, but I figured that it worked differently back then and that's why I didn't downvote. The comment was made just for clarifying this detail for people reading this.